# "The debugger backend could not be started." Eric 6 IDE Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, editor, eric-ide

New to python, used Matlab previously.

I get an error message: "The debugger backend could not be started." when I try to run any script in Eric IDE editor for python. (I am using various simple code examples for importing and visualizing data. An example of borrowed code is below.)

I installed python 3.6, and Python 3.5 (should I uninstall one of these?)
I downloaded Eric to use as an editor and debugger and installed as an administrator.

In the [Eric Python documentation](https://eric-ide.python-projects.org/documentation/Eric6-TR_160400.pdf) I did not find a solution. I did look in preferences for debugging and tried both the path for Python 3.5 as well as Python 3.6
I am not sure what I changed or broke as a script had worked from the "shell" tab in Eric previously. So I broke something and cannot fix it.

Should I try uninstalling Eric, and both versions of Python (3.5 and 3.6) and starting over from scratch?

I think my issue may have something to do with paths, file locations etc., installation directories, really not sure and cannot find anything helpful online after much searching.

I also am not certain know what paths (full directory filenames) should be in "Interpreter:" and "Working directory:" in the "Run Script" window.

Any help much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Rebecca

```
# Numpy (data import, manipulation, export)
import numpy as np
# Matplotlib (create trends)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the data file
data_file = np.genfromtxt('data_file.txt', delimiter=',')

# create time vector from imported data (starts from index 0)
time = data_file[:,0]
# parse good sensor data from imported data
sensors = data_file[:,1:5]

# display the first 6 sensor rows
print(sensors[0:6])

# adjust time to start at zero by subtracting the
#  first element in the time vector (index = 0)
time = time - time[0]

# calculate the average of the sensor readings
avg = np.mean(sensors,1) # over the 2nd dimension

# export data
# stack time and avg as column vectors
my_data = np.vstack((time,sensors.T,avg))
# transpose data
my_data = my_data.T
# save text file with comma delimiter
np.savetxt('export_from_python.txt',my_data,delimiter=',')

# generate a figure
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(time/60.0,sensors[:,1],'ro')
plt.plot(time/60.0,avg,'b.')
# add text labels to the plot
plt.legend(['Sensor 2','Average Sensors 1-4'])
plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
plt.ylabel('Sensor Values')
# save the figure as a PNG file
plt.savefig('my_Python_plot.png')
# show the figure on the screen (pauses execution until closed)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I found this in the manual, and re-set my confirguration. Reset User Configuration
If desired, Eric “First time usage” condition can be reset simply erasing the “*.ini” files
you'll fine inside167 your <User>\AppData\Roaming\Eric6 “hidden” directory168; next Eric run will
thus execute as it were the first.-

Answer (score 0):

1. I  re-set my configuration by deleting *.ini files. (From Eric6 documentation)"Reset User Configuration. If desired, Eric “First time usage” condition can be reset simply erasing the “*.ini” files you'll find inside your \AppData\Roaming\Eric6 “hidden” directory; next Eric run will
   thus execute as it were the first.-"
2. Then I followed the very helpful instructions on this page (http://techattitude.com/tips-tricks-and-hacks/how-to-install-eric6-ide-for-python-on-windows/) a second time, by resetting the following:
3. In eric6: settings, preferences, autocompletion, Qsintilla. Selected "from document and API files"
4. In eric6: settings, preferences, editor, APIs: Language, Python3, made sure Python-3.5.api was listed under APIs.
5. I clicked on "compile APIs. For both Python3 language dropdown and repeated the same for QScintilla.

No longer getting the error message that the debugger is not starting!  ;) Updating this post in case this answer helps someone else. I think the problem was a result of not knowing what's installed where, what's in the path and/or working directory location, and/or python and Qsintilla version. Not 100% sure. A possible result of not being sure which items were installed in which directories when I installed various things (Python, Eric etc.) and maybe not checking off "add to path" during an installation of python or a module.